# How to retrieve Date value from Database using C#.net and set in HTML5 input Type 'date'?

Tags: c#, html, date

I want to retrieve date from database and set into HTML5 input type 'date'. I have two HTML5 date fields with IDs 'CourseStartDate' and 'CourseEndDate', and using the following code but couldn't getting the value in HTML5 date.

```
   CourseStartDate.Value  = coursedr["Start_Date"].ToString();
   CourseEndDate.Value    = coursedr["End_Date"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to convert the date time into specific format accepted by HTML5 control.

```
CourseStartDate.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Hope this will help.