# Display date in TextBox with type="date"

Tags: vb.net, date, textbox

I want to display stored date on database on `TextBox`  `type="date"`

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="DateStatus"  runat="server" Type="date" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

but nothing is displayed in the textbox i used. I tried this

```
Dim getdate As Date = DetailTable.Rows(0)(3)
DateStatus.Text= getDate
```

Also this which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263632/how-to-retrieve-date-value-from-database-using-c-net-and-set-in-html5-input-typ)

```
 Dim getdate As Date = DetailTable.Rows(0)(3)
 DateStatus.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(getdate)
```

When i debugged the code, the date passed correctly. 
When i remove `type="date"`   the requested date is displayed just fine

Is it not Possible to do this?

on SideNote when i generate my table using `<Asp:detailsview>` the date is generated with time `12:00:00` despite the field declared only as `Date`in the schema, but i don't think it's relevant to my current issue since every thing looked fine during debugging

And Originally i store the date as Text `(@date, DateStatus.Text)`

Comment: "22/05/2019 12:00:00 am". What is the current culture? the date format in the input type is mm/dd/yyyy @Rango

Comment: What about `DateStatus.Text = getDate.ToString()` or even `DateStatus.Text = getDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is HTML 5 stuff. If you have a real date from your database, I simulated like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" TextMode="date" />

        Dim d As New Date(1922, 12, 25)
        txt1.Text = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        'displays 12/25/1922
```

HTML 5 expects a string in the format yyyy-MM-dd and a supporting browser will display depending on Culture setting.